# Icon resources in a Java shebang application

Tags: java, java-shebang

I have a Java shebang script, it shows some UI (JFrame etc.) and I have to provide icons "Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Reset Zoom", probably some more.

***How do I use icons from within a Java shebang script?***

I do development under Linux, but the user might be using Windows or Mac. (I did not try to run my app on Windows or Mac yet.) I use a shebang script because I want the user to receive just one executable file. Probably there are other options.

UPD
As a workaround I use `static void loadIcon(JButton button, String resourcePath, String altText)` that sets the button's text ***if*** the icon cannot be loaded. As a result, the application looks a bit uglier when run as a script, but running as a script is still possible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to provide a jar file? Then you can include resources inside it.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an icon for Linux you would usually place some icon files in different sizes and formats (at least one with 32x32 pixels .png) into the same folder where the startup script is or in an "icons" subfolder. Then the user can configure that icon together with his start-menu entry. Your program may also provide a configuration scripts that adds the start-menu entry automatically, but there are so many different desktop version on the market each with its own method. I would leave that to the user to do it manually.

Shebang scripts wont work under Windows unless the user installs CygWin or a Linux Subsystem.

For Windows, you have to write a .cmd or .bat script, however they can also not have an embedded icon. Therefore many Java programs for windows are delivered with an startup .exe which runs the start script. The .exe can contain an icon. The .exe program must be developed with a Microsoft specific development environment. You can find the instructions in the Microsoft Knowledge base.

There are free tools available which generate such wrapper programs. One of them is described in this tutorial: https://medium.com/@sulabh4/how-to-make-a-executable-file-from-your-java-code-3f521938ae5c

Answer (score 0):

You could always generate your own icons in code:

```
#!/usr/bin/java --source 11

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class StarIcon extends JPanel {

  private static final int I_SIZE = 40;
  private static final double D_SIZE = I_SIZE;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Star Icon");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.add(new StarIcon(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  
  StarIcon() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    Image image = makeStarImage();
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Star", icon, SwingConstants.LEFT);

    // double the font size, just for fun.
    Font labelFont = label.getFont();
    label.setFont(labelFont.deriveFont(labelFont.getSize()*2.0f));

    final int ms = I_SIZE*10;
    final Color bg = label.getBackground();
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(ms, ms, ms, ms, bg));
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, label);
  }

  private static Image makeStarImage() {
    final double starRad = D_SIZE * 0.4;
    Point2D[] points = {
        toRect(starRad, 0.0),
        toRect(starRad, 144.0),
        toRect(starRad, 288.0),
        toRect(starRad, 72.0),
        toRect(starRad, 216.0),
        toRect(starRad, 0.0)
    };
    double center = D_SIZE/2.0;
    double side = D_SIZE;
    double arc = D_SIZE*0.3;
    RoundRectangle2D border = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, side, side, arc, arc);

    GeneralPath star = new GeneralPath();
    star.moveTo(points[0].getX(), points[0].getY());
    for (int i=1; i<points.length; ++i) {
      star.lineTo(points[i].getX(), points[i].getY());
    }
    Image image = new BufferedImage(I_SIZE, I_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
    );

    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fill(border);
    AffineTransform savedTransform = g2.getTransform();
    g2.translate(center, center);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fill(star);
    g2.setTransform(savedTransform);
    g2.dispose();
    return image;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
  private static Point2D toRect(double r, double thetaDeg) {
    double thetaRad = (thetaDeg * Math.PI) / 180.0;
    final double x = r * StrictMath.sin(thetaRad);
    final double y = -r * StrictMath.cos(thetaRad);
    return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
  }
}
```